r3f pass object3d to boxhelper
I aim to create boxhelpers using boxgeometries. However, I've been struggling passing the mesh object to the boxHelper args using react three fiber syntax. This is what I tried:
 const meshRef = useRef();

  <object3D>
    <mesh ref={meshRef}>
      <boxGeometry args={[0.4, 0.4, 0.4]} />
      <meshBasicMaterial
        color={"red"}
        transparent
        opacity={0.2}
      />
    </mesh>
    {meshRef.current && (
      <boxHelper args={[meshRef.current, "red"]} />
    )}
  </object3D>

however, the reference is not passed straight away which in turns the boxhelper does not gets displayed in the scene
